# For $R = R_{1} \oplus R_{2}$, where $I_{1}$ ideal of $R_{1}$, $I_{2}$ ideal of $R_{2}$, show that $I_{1},I_{2}$ ideals of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, direct-sum, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R = R_{1} \oplus R_{2}$ and let $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ be ideals of rings $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$, respectively.

We consider $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ as subrings of $R$ under canonical embeddings $R_{i} \to R$ and thus $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ are considered as subrings of $R$.

I need to do the following two things:

> a. Prove that $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ are ideals of $R$.
>
> b. If each $I_{i}$ is a proper ideal of $R_{i}$, determine whether the ideal $I_{1}+I_{2}$ of $R$ is maximal. Is it prime?

For part (a), if we identify $I_{1} = I_{1}\times 0$, then in order for it to be an ideal of $R$, I need it to be both an additive subgroup of $R_{1} \times R_{2}$ and I would need $(R_{1}\times R_{2})(I_{1}) \subseteq I_{1}$ and $(I_{1})(R_{1} \times R_{2}) \subseteq I_{1}$. The latter two things especially are confusing me because of the direct sum notation.

Could anybody assist me with this part especially - hints for part (b) as to how to get at least started are also welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you need any isomorphism theorem, but rather you should see how multiplication behaves between $R_1$ and $R_2$

Comment: @Max if $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are any two rings such that $R = R_{1} \oplus R_{2}$, how would I determine that?

Comment: Your cannonical embedings are not ring homomorphisms nor are $R_1$ or $R_2$ subrings.

Comment: @JJR why are $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ not subrings?

Comment: Because they don't share the same unit $1_R$ see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring.

Comment: @JJR even if that is true, all I did was copy the problem exactly as it appeared in my assignment, which included all that stuff about them being subrings. Assuming those premises are all true, how can I show that $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ are ideals of the direct sum $R$?

Comment: @JJR Perhaps ALannister is using $R_1\oplus R_2$ for the coproduct in the category of rings. That being said, he should clarify it.

Comment: By looking at the definition of the "direct sum". The multiplication there is pointwise and $I_i$ is a copy $I_i\times {0}$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli interesting proposal :)

Comment: @JJR then, in order for $I_{1} = I_{1}\times 0$ to be an ideal of $R$, I need it to be both an additive subgroup of $R_{1} \times R_{2}$ and I would need $(R_{1}\times R_{2})(I_{1}) \subseteq I_{1}$ and $(I_{1})(R_{1} \times R_{2}) \subseteq I_{1}$. The latter two things especially are confusing me because of the direct sum notation

Comment: @ALannister Ah, ok. So you were asking for $R_1\times R_2$. I strongly recommend you stick to the $\times$ notation when talking about rings.

Comment: @ALannister just for everybody to be on the same page; Are your "direct sums" products or coporducts in the category of rings with unit?

Comment: @JJR I honestly don't know what a "coproduct in the category of rings with unit" is. It's possible that my professor does, though, and that's why he thinks he can get away with using this notation.

Comment: @ALannister no probs. You probably mean products.

Comment: @JJR : rings are sometimes defined without a unit, in which case $R_1$ and $R_2$ are indeed subrings

Comment: @Max, yes! For us most rings do not have a unit. They only have a unit if we specify that they do. No such thing for us as Rngs

Comment: @Max Rngs vs Rings should not become a topic here if you know what I mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these it is helpful to keep a particular product in mind. Namely, $R$ is the ring of pairs $(r_1, r_2)$ under pointwise product and sum. $R_1$ are all the pairs $(r_1, 0)$ and $R_2$ is all the pairs $(0,r_2)$. Note that $R_1R_2 = 0$ and $R_1 + R_2 = R$.

a) The ideal $I_1$ corresponds to pairs $(i,0)$ where $i \in I_1$ as a subset of $R_1$. Then $RI_1$ = $(R_1 + R_2)I_1 = R_1I_1 + R_2I_1 = R_1I_1 = I_1$ because $R_2I_1 = 0$.

b) $I_1 + I_2$ is prime if and only if $R/(I_1 + I_2)$ is a domain. Hint: are products of rings usually domains?

Comment: for part (b), we know that direct sums of nontrivial rings have zero divisors, so no.

Comment: also for part (a), why is $(R_{1} + R_{2})I_{1} = R_{1}I_{1} + R_{2}I_{2}$? Where did that $I_{2}$ come from?

Comment: @ALannister The subscript was an error. For part b) you have it exactly. In fact, you might like to show that $R/(I_1 + I_2) \cong R_1/I_1 \oplus R_1/I_2$ and since $I_1$ and $I_2$ are proper... You can also do this directly by finding two elements in $R$ which aren't in $I_1 + I_2$ but their product is.

Comment: actually, I have to disagree with you about what you said regarding part (b). In order for $I_{1} + I_{2}$ to be prime if and only if $R/(I_{1}+I_{2})$ is a(n integral) domain, $R$ needs to be a non-zero commutative ring with identity. I never said it had to be. FYI, I'm not working in a rng vs. ring framework. When I say ring, I mean that it does not have the identity unless I specifically say that it has the identity. I also never said anywhere that it had to be commutative. So I don't think that argument works here.

Comment: @ALannister The point is that it's the same idea. If $I_1$ is proper then $R_1$ contains an element $r_1$ which is not in $I_1$ and similarly, if $I_2$ is proper you can find such an $r_2$. Then $r_1, r_2 \not\in I_1 + I_2$ but $r_1r_2 \in I_1 + I_2$.

Comment: that's to show that $I_{1}+I_{2}$ is not prime? What about maximal?

Comment: @ALannister Maximal ideals are prime. You can also see directly that $R_1 + I_2$ and $I_1 + R_2$ are larger proper ideals.